# Converting an int to a char in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, return-value

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* intToString(int N);
int power(int N, int M)
{   
    int n = N;
    if (M ==0) return 1;
    int i;
    for( i = 1; i < M; i++)
        N*=n;
    return N;
}

int main()
{
   printf("%s",intToString(100));
}

char* intToString(int N)
{   
   float M = N;
   int numberLen = 1;
   while(M > 1) 
   { 
      M /= 10;numberLen++;
   }
   int ar[numberLen];
   char str[numberLen + 1];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < numberLen; i++)
   {
      str[numberLen - i - 1] = (N%power(10,i+1))/(power(10,i));
   }
   str[numberLen] = '\0';
   return str; 
}
```

I am trying to solve the Euler project problems in C. I have run into a little issue here, when I run this program I get a square with some numbers in it as oppose to a string "100".

Comment: snprintf is really useful for this

Comment: In your code, consider using binary exponentiation instead of linear - it takes O(log2(n)) time, instead of O(n) (where n is the exponent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
 char str[numberLen + 1];
```

`str` is local to your function `intToString`.

If you try to return a pointer to this array and try to make use of the return value in the caller function, it will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as when the function finishes execution, the array cease to exist and the returned pointer renders invalid. Attempt to make use of invalid memory invokes UB.

You can make `str` a pointer and use dynamic memory allocation functions like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family to allocate memory to that. In that case, even if the function finishes execution, the lifetime of the allocated memory remains valid until [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)-d explicitly and making use of the return value is not an error.

Comment: Ahhh. I should know better! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution suggested by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152623/434551), you can pass an array of `char` from `main` to `intToString`. That will avoid the need to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
char* intToString(int N, char* buffer);

...

int main()
{
   char buffer[20]; // Make it large enough for your need.
   printf("%s",intToString(100, buffer));
}

char* intToString(int N, char* buffer)
{
   // Replace use of str by buffer

   ...

   return buffer;
}
```